# how to use these sundry determiners: a, another, the other, some, the others

Tags: determiners

Next cases are the ones I translated from a Korean [sentnece](http://dic.daum.net/search.do?q=%EB%98%90%20%EB%8B%A4%EB%A5%B8&t=example&dic=kor): “어떤 장사꾼은 칼을 가지런히 벌여 놓았고 또 다른 장사꾼은 여러 가지 그릇을 벌여 놓았다.” What I’d like to know is if (1.1)~(2.2) all can be proper in English.

> 1. **A** seller placed his knives neatly, (1.1) **another**/ (1.2 ) **the other** placed various pottery in disorder.
>   2. **Some** sellers placed their knives neatly, (2.1) **some**/ (2.2) **the others** placed various pottery in disorder.

Are the above all be used right? If any ones can’t, how should the ones be corrected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important point to be observed here is that you use *the NOUN* only when your hearer can be expected to know which *NOUN* you are talking about because either a) you have already mentioned it, or b) you will define it as soon as you have named it, or c) it is common knowledge the two of you share.

> 1. A seller placed his knives neatly, (1.1)another / (1.2)the other placed various pottery in disorder.

In set 1, (1.2)***the*** other is probably ungrammatical. This expression implies one of a pair of sellers you have already mentioned. But the first seller cannot have been identified before you mention him, since you speak of him with the indefinite determiner; this implies that you have not mentioned the pair. Consequently the second seller cannot be ***the*** other of the pair: he can only be (1.1)***an**other* seller.

In set 2, (2.2)***the*** others may be grammatical or may not. ***Some*** determines an indefinite **number** of sellers, but it does not imply that the sellers belong to a group which you have already mentioned; consequently *some* may be applied either to previously undefined sellers or to members of a previously defined group. If you have already mentioned the entire group of sellers, then ***the*** others is grammatical: it designates all of the group who did not place their knives neatly. But if you have not mentioned the group, then your hearer does not know the group of which they are members, and ***the*** others is ungrammatical.

Comment: I thank you. * In the third line, there seems to be a typo: share

Answer (score 1):

I think the better choice is in 2:

> **Some** sellers placed their knives neatly; **some/the others** placed various pottery in disorder.

You should use a semi-colon as there are two independent clauses. Or say:

> **Some** sellers placed their knives neatly, **while some/the others** placed various pottery in disorder.

Use of *some* or *the others* in the second clause could be OK depending on the context. *some* if you are not talking about every seller, or *the others* if you are talking about every seller.

In 1) **A seller** and **the other** use mismatched pronouns (indefinite vs. definite). So I would say:

> **A** seller placed his knives neatly; **another** placed various pottery in disorder.

or use *while* as mentioned above. This assumes there could be other sellers not mentioned here.

Comment: In case of only two sellers I would use "One seller" - "the other".